# How do I extract a file out of a virtual disk?

Tags: c++, c, filesystems, ntfs, ext3

Given a block of data (which the filesystem thinks is the whole drive) and the type of filesystem (fat32, ntfs, ext3) I would like to know how to extract files out of that block of data. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: "Which the filesystem thinks is the whole drive" -- I think you mean "which the guest operating system thinks is an attached physical disk."  Filesystems have no concept of drives.

Answer (score 2):

You ultimately have two options:

1. Mount the filesystem contained in the virtual disk image on the host machine.  Tools like `losetup` can be helpful to accomplish this.
2. Find an appropriate library that will allow you to poke at the volume in userspace.  Basically, you want a user-mode filesystem driver that will let a program inspect the directory structure and extract files.  You might be able to repurpose parts of fuse-ext2 and ntfs-3g.

This all assumes that the virtual disk is just a flat image file, not a specialized container like VMDK or VDI.  If it is, you'll either need to extract the flat image or find a library that is capable of providing the flat content to other libraries.

Comment: #1 seems really messy or slow because you wouldnt know when to unmount. You could probably unmount immediately after the call, but that would be really slow.

Comment: @chacham15: on the other hand, you would use the same kernel driver that is used normally to mount that filesystem (so it should be very reliable), and the extraction would become just a normal file copy from the mount point to your target directory.

Answer (score 0):

You mount it to some point using

```
mount image /mount/point -o loop,ro
```

and access the files in it. Afterwards, you can unmount again.

But I do not understan what this has to do with C or C++.

Comment: Unfortunately, this direct approach won't work if the virtual disk has a partition table.  You'd first have to run `losetup` and give it the byte offset to the partition.